# Telegram bot link with geo:uri

Tags: gps, telegram, geo, telegram-api

Did someone know, if i can use geo:uri scheme while sending message by telegram bot with HTML parse mode?
Something like

```
<a href="geo:37.786971,-122.399677">here</a>
```

seems didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: found any answers?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using sendLocation instead?

Like this:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botAPI:TOKEN/sendLocation?chat_id=CHATID&latitude=42.08324631&longitude=12.4886930452,1
```

Here are some reference and a tool for testing:

https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/reference/sendlocation